# How to lock home screen icons folders dragging deleting settings

Tags: lock-screens, launcher, app-icons, app-drawer, nova-launcher

**Question How to lock home screen icons folders dragging deleting settings**

I have rooted my mobiles and installed Nova launcher now on home screen i have categroized apps icons in circle folders. As the phone is also used by kids and family members   whole opening touching the mistakenly drag or delte the icon on home screen folders  mistakenly

How can in rooted phone I can lock the home screen or drawer or  folder icons or new notifications from deleting or dragging or changing...or from settings changes without pin or administrative  permissions . Is it possible through app or adb shell commands kindly suggest.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/NovaLauncher/comments/icdk06/is_there_a_way_to_lock_home_screen_apps_in_place

Answer (score 0):

Settings - home screen - scroll down to the bottom.... advanced - lock desktop

Comment: bro  the Nova liancher many time automatically disappears and overdrawn by original android native launcher 3 ......how can we lock on laincher 3....some one suggested me multisuer or guest option in android's setting.>andvanced>multi user but on android 5.1.1 or android 6 ther is no settings>advanced menu..kindly suggest if any app available for the same

Comment: Link2SD not only is app for symlinks it's also great app manager where you can search/share/freeze apks or make user apps system apps. freeze the stock launcher3